# git fetch に、 --prune がオプションなのは何故？

Tags: git

スタックオーバーフロー向けなのか分かりませんが。質問してみます。

私は、いつも`git config --global fetch.prune true`しているのですが。
そもそもなぜrefsが残るのでしょう。そして、なぜオプション扱いなのでしょうか。
refsを残したほうがいい場合というのが思いつきません。

というのも「pruneすれば消える」という情報は直ぐ見つかるのですが
「こういう時は、pruneしてはいけない！」という情報が見つからず、おまじない化していることに不安を覚えました。

pruneしてはいけない代表的な事例とは、どういう状況でしょうか。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

代表的かどうかはわかりませんが、例えばこんなケースでしょうか?

1. 隣の人からあるブランチを引き継ぎたいので、（originを経由せずに）その人のレポジトリをremoteとして追加し、直接fetch
2. 隣の人は、渡し終わったのでローカルブランチを削除
3. 取得したリモートブランチからローカルブランチを作成する前に、別のブランチを更新しようとしてもう一度fetch
4. pruneしていたので、先に取得したリモートブランチも消えてしまう

デフォルトがpruneになっていないのは、安全側に倒すためではないでしょうか。

Comment: あー。なるほど。確かにそういう手続きをしてしまうと問題ですね。git側の破壊的(destructive)だからというだけじゃなくて、事例がわかるとしっくりきました。@snakさん、@3100さん、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 7):

[fetch: make --prune configurable · 737c5a9 · git/git](https://github.com/git/git/commit/737c5a9cde708d6995c765b7c2e95033edd0a896)

> Since --prune is a potentially destructive operation (Git doesn't
>   keep reflogs for deleted references yet), we don't want to prune
>   without users consent, so this configuration will not be on by
>   default.

とのことで、安全性を考慮してこのようになっているようです。